# How to write the junit test case for a function

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a method in a class in which I have used the String Retry mechanism..
And my code is:

```
@Override
    @Retryable(
            value={RuntimeException.class,IOException.class},
            maxAttempts=3,
            backoff=@Backoff(delay=5000)
            )
    public void sampleService(String payLoad, String type) throws HttpException, IOException
             {
        StringRequestEntity requestEntity = null;
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod();
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int statusCode;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        StringBuffer eventResponse = new StringBuffer();
        String jsonReceive = null;
        try{
            requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(payLoad, MEDIA_TYPE, FORMAT);
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                postMethod = new PostMethod(baseServiceUrl + apiItemServiceUrl);
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("itemGroup")) {
                postMethod = new PostMethod(baseServiceUrl
                        + apiItemGroupServiceUrl);
            }
            postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
            statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
            log.info("Status code from item service call: " + statusCode);
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Error in service call");

            }
            inputStream = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            if (null != inputStream) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                        FORMAT));
                for (line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                    eventResponse = eventResponse.append(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.info("Exception occurs " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Exception occurs " + e);
        }
            jsonReceive = eventResponse.toString();
            log.info("JsonReceive from the Service" + jsonReceive);


    }
```

I want to write the Junit test case for the above method and should be retry for more than one times when an exception occurs.Can anyone help me to write the test case??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JUnit, you can chain return statements to have a different behavior on each call, e.g.:

```
when(httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod))
   .thenReturn(errorCode)
   .thenReturn(anotherErrorCode)
   .thenReturn(200)
```